# Creating a control that covers the whole area except a particular area

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to create a control that covers the whole area except a particular area. This particular area will be in an ellipse/rectangle shape. Something like the below concept

[image]

My idea is to use paths. Below is my code for the path.

```
<Path Name="ShowcasePath" StrokeThickness="1" IsHitTestVisible="True">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="100" RadiusY="50"/>
            <RectangleGeometry/>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

`Centre` of the `EllipseGeometry` and `Rect` of the `RectangleGeometry` will be set in code behind.

This method has two problems

1. The fill colour is semi-transparent even with no alpha value. The final colour will be transparent white. So it's not a real problem.
2. The item inside the ellipse should be fully functional and items outside the ellipse should be non-functional.

[image]

Any idea for solving the above issues?

or Any different idea for this control?

Comment: That giant red box is really hard on the eyes!

Comment: @RonBeyer The final colour will be transparent white.

Comment: I understand it is just a mock-up of what you want covered, it is just difficult to look at (at least on my LCD's). Maybe a better option would be to bind everything else's `Visibility` so that everything other than what you want shown is set to hidden?

Comment: @RonBeyer No, all controls should be visible through the semi-transparent white. So I can't set `Visibility ` to so this.

Comment: Bind all controls'a(except for the one you want to keep active) `IsEnabled` property and then set it to `False` when required.Happy coding :)

Comment: @zackraiyan I want to create a `CustomControl` that sit top of all other control. So it's not possible. Also, setting `IsEnabled` will change the look of a control.

Comment: If you customize the template of the controls(i know it's a bit workaround),then u may get rid of the non-enabled look change problem...

Comment: @zackraiyan I think you didn't get the point. That control can anything (like Grid, GridView, Button, RadioButton). My custom control should overlap all the controls expect the highlighted control. All other control should we inactive.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with a customControl or not(maybe it is) but the only way that comes to mind is a shape with inverse shape that only leaves the circled area. :(

Comment: You're going to run into a couple of gotchas in this scenario. One, unless the parent panel hosting your overlay remains fixed size, having a custom Path will only skew your open area so the output will be unpredictable unless you manually create the path data on the fly. Clip isn't an option here. Then there's also the caveat that the underlying UIElements will still be tab-able/action-able even if you can't click them unless you handle that as well. However, you could get creative with your DOM order and give the ILLUSION of this effect without any of that mess if you'd like an example

Comment: @ChrisW. I will change path data on the fly. I didn't understand the second problem. Also Maybe, we can create a control in the visual layer but I am not familiar will it.

Comment: You may be able to create an Adorner layer and add your "cover" control to that.

Comment: If you're already comfortable creating the path data on the fly to get your cut-out area that's the first step. However your overlay while it may prevent direct click/hover events....it's still going to allow the user keyboard interaction to the elements behind the overlay by default such as Tab/Enter. So you'll have to disable either each element like @zackraiyan pointed out, or create your layout in such a way you can `IsHitTestVisible=False` whole sections of layout while keep your single UIElement available for required events by itself.

Comment: @ChrisW.,thanks for pointing out the `IsHittestVisible` property..Totally missed it

Comment: @ChrisW. I already tried `IsHitTestVisible` with my path but it didn't work for the path. Which make sense because paths are just lines, it is not a solid control. So the new question is "How to create custom shapes without paths?"

Comment: Nah you would apply it to the parent container of all the UIElements, and all the children UIElements of that container would automagically ignore all hit events. The overlay doesn't care what's under it in the DOM order, but a parent panel will control its children.

Comment: @zackraiyan oh ya, learned that one the hard way once where having a ton of elements looking for propertychange caused a big 'ol performance issue until a single bool on the parents hittestvisibility made a huge difference... Now if you asked me where my car keys might be, I probably wouldn't be as helpful since half the time I have no idea lol

Comment: Why not go with blend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were already pretty close with your example, at least I can't find anything wrong with it. If you try the following code, you will see it does exactly what you described:

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Clickable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="113,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Non-Clickable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="272,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Path Name="ShowcasePath" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#88ff0000" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
                <EllipseGeometry Center="150,100" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="50"/>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,500,500"/>
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Keep in mind however, that users could still change the focused element with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and activate elements with <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>, even if you set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false`.

The "focus the ellipse on an element" functionality can easily be taken care of like this:

```cs
public void FocusOnElement(FrameworkElement element)
{
    Point center = new Point(element.ActualWidth / 2, element.ActualHeight / 2);
    Point newPosition = element.TranslatePoint(center, ShowcasePath);
    ellipseGeometry.Center = newPosition;
}
```

The enable/disable all other elements functionality would best be taken care of in your viewmodel, or if you don't have one, kind of like this:

```cs
private void DiableAllButThisAndItsParents(FrameworkElement thisElement)
{
    List<FrameworkElement> hierarchy = FindParents(thisElement).ToList();

    foreach (FrameworkElement element in hierarchy)
    {
        element.IsEnabled = true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(element, thisElement)) continue;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
            if (!(child is FrameworkElement childElement)) continue;

            childElement.IsEnabled = hierarchy.Contains(childElement);
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> FindParents(FrameworkElement element)
{
    DependencyObject current = element;

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current is FrameworkElement)
            yield return (FrameworkElement) current;
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
}
```

Put that all together and it should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to mess with `IsEnabled` because it will change the look

Comment: @VijayNirmal Well you can of course use any combination of the techniques mentioned above.

Comment: `IsHitTestVisible` work properly. Yesterday, it didn't work. But another problem with my approach is, every control inside the ellipse is intractable. suppose I have a button 1 and button 2 near to each other then even if the button 1 is highlighted we can still click button 2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get a element which is "Click-through" you can simply bring the Element (in your case the togglebutton) to the front (basically above everything else so that it is clickable).
You can do this by either of the following:

1. change the element's ZIndexProperty so that it comes to the front.
    `YourElement.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, index);`
2. Remove the element and add it again to the parent grid(thus it will basically be the last element to be added)

   `parentGrid.Children.Remove(YourElement);
   parentGrid.Children.Add(YourElement);
   parentGrid.UpdateLayout();`

After the user has successfully interacted with the control you can switch it back to the way it was before.. Hope this helps..

Comment: Expect for highlighted item, interaction for all item should be turned off. Also, I want to create a custom control.